# What is the purpose of .`ToListAsync()`

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

If I try to run this code

```
await _dbContext.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
```

I will get this error :

> InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068

By following the provided [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068) we can read the following statement

> [...] because they are only designed to be used with Entity Framework you may receive the following error if you try to use them on a LINQ query that isn’t an Entity Framework query.

Then why can't I use it on a DbSet ? To me a DbSet is clearly an entity-framework related class since it is found in the EntityFramework assembly ...

As per the [DbSet MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx), it implements `IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()`. If the `IDbAsyncEnumerable` is implemented, why can't `.ToListAsync()` run ?

Plus, by digging into the code using the ReSharper decompiler I couldn't understand at which point it goes wrong ... the `AsDbAsyncEnumerable` method that is internally used tries to cast my `DbSet<T>` into an `IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>` which should work since `DbSet` implements it ...

At this point my code uses the following line, which is exactly what I expected `.ToListAsync()` was doing internally.

```
await _dbContext.Set<T>().ToAsyncEnumerable().ToList();
```

Why isn't `ToAsyncEnumerable` used internally ? In which case would `ToListAsync` be used if it doesn't work on either a normal `IQueryable` nor a `DbSet` ?

Comment: Post a *reproducible* example. *Which* framework and *which* database are you targeting? EF6 is not EF Core 2.0. I'm using `ToListAsync` although I prefer `ToArrayAsync`

Comment: You tagged both Ef6 and EfCore2, make up your mind first.

Comment: That might be a bad mix...  ToListAsync() is an extension method.

Comment: So i checked. I'm using EF 6 ... i'll switch to EF core and see what happens.

Comment: Don't just switch, also make sure you only use 1 set of tools/packages.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, if fixed it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panagiotis Kanavos and Henk Holterman pointed out the right thing in the comments: EF6 isn't EF Core. For some reason I simply assumed that these two were the same, with "core" being a fancy name used as an alias. It's probably for this reason that I ended up having both in my project.

I tried a lot of things to fix the error but ultimately I fixed everything by simply removing every single package that could have been more or less remotely related to Entity Framework from my project except for `Microsoft.NETCore.App` because it's mandatory in .netcote 2.0 apps. From there I started adding packages depending on what name-spaces and classes the compiler was crying about using MSDN to find the package's names and it ultimately worked again.

Now to properly answer my question: `ToListAsync()` does exactly what it's supposed to do. It just doesn't recognise an EF6 `DbContext` since, it's not part of the EFCore package. So mixing these two up isn't a good idea.